# Triggered Email not working since migrating to V8 Runtime

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax, triggers

First let me state that all my coding is self taught so my knowledge is functional but not deep. I am creating a Google sheet for my HR team in my company to track Paid Time Off. I had built triggers to send emails when time was submitted. It worked before the migration to V8 but doesn't now, and I don't know enough about syntax to be able to find the issue.

```
function sendNotification(e){

  if(e.range.getColumn()=13 && e.value='Yes')

{
 //Employee Name and Email Address
 var EmployeeName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("R3"); 
 var Employee = EmployeeName.getValue(); 
 var EmployeeEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("S3");
 var EmployeeEmailAddress = EmployeeEmailRange.getValues();

 //Approver Name and Email Address
 var ApproverName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("R4"); 
 var Approver = ApproverName.getValue();
 var ApproverEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("S4");
 var ApproverEmailAddress = ApproverEmailRange.getValues();

 //HR Email Address
 var HREmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("S5");
 var HREmailAddress = HREmailRange.getValues();

 //Link to Employee's PTO Spreadsheet 
 var SheetLink = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PTO Earnings").getRange("R1"); 
 var Link = SheetLink.getValue();

 //Email Content
 var subject = 'PTO Submitted for '+Employee+' for '+e.range.getSheet().getName()+'.';
 var body = 'Dear '+Approver+','+"\n\n"+'A PTO Request has been submitted by: '+Employee+', at:'+"\n\n"+Link +"\n\n"+'Thank you.'+"\n\n"+'Imagine This HR';
 var recipient = [EmployeeEmailAddress, ApproverEmailAddress,HREmailAddress];

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
 }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that un-migrating is optional, but Google is auto-migrating scripts to V8.

Part of the problem is that Google is automatically migrating scripts that pass their compatibility tests. And apparently some use of MailApp.sendEmail will pass the test but will in fact fail when the script is run.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#automatic_migration_of_scripts_to_v8

This required me to revert/opt out in about 30 sheets that use MailApp just to ensure they don't fail - users really need scripts to work.

There is no mention of MailApp.sendEmail compatibility issues in any of the migration help docs.

Answer (score 0):

The migration to V8 is optional. If you aren't ready or you don't have time to make your code compatible with it, just disable it. To do this, click Run > Disable new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of triggers don't work with V8 Runtime migration.
I have a trigger on onOpen () and it doesn't work when the sheet is opened by a collaborator. However, it works well when it is opened by the owner. I haven't found a solution yet ...